# How to clear these styles

Tags: css, datatables-1.10

I am using a 3rd part bootstrap theme that defines a nice-looking UI for forms via the "smart-form" class. I need to incorporate a DataTable into the form and that DataTable looks messed up. My html looks kind of like that:

```
<form class="smart-form">
   .... form controls ....
   <div class="data-table">....</div>
   .... form controls ....
</form>
```

I tracked the problem down to these styles from `smart-form` being applied to `datatable`:

```
.smart-form *, .smart-form :after, .smart-form :before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

If in Chrome I uncheck these styles, my data table looks fine.

Can I apply some styles to the data table DIV to prevent these styles from smart-form propagating to the data table?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit the theme's stylesheet? Or insert a stylesheet of your own that overrides the theme one? Or add a style attribute to the div?

Comment: I can insert the style sheet of my own and override the styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `.smart-form *`. `*` means all elements inside `.smart-form`. You need to workaround something like this:

```
  .smart-form > *:not(.datatable *)
```

That means: *all children inside `.smart-form` that not match with all elements inside `.datatable`*

Comment: This works -- I had to add not(.datatable *) with an asterisk. The only issue is that I had to modified that 3rd party stylesheet, so in case of an update from the vendor, the change will be lost. I wish there was a way to override this in my own stylesheet, but I couldn't find a way to do that.

Comment: @user1044169, see [the answer from @dfsq](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32461417/3549014), that way you don't have to edit third-party stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cancel applied styles with `inherit` rule:

```
.smart-form .data-table,
.smart-form .data-table *, 
.smart-form .data-table :after, 
.smart-form .data-table :before {
    margin: inherit;
    padding: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you include these rules after 3rd party stylesheet.